# Requests not returning html tags

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape YouTube with requests and beautiful soup. I need to get the number of views. It is contained in a div tag with class="watch-view-count" but sometimes the request object won't have the tag I am looking for. How to ensure that the request object has the tag that I am looking for.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
markup = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSb1_lHcSsg').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup.text,'html.parser')
views = soup.findAll('div',{ "class":"watch-view-count"})
```

Sometimes the variable markup won't have any div tag with class=watch-view-count instead it mostly contains javascript code.

Comment: Please, provide your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try [pafy](https://pypi.org/project/pafy/) to get viewcount, duration, rating, author, thumbnail, keywords etc.

```
import pafy
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSb1_lHcSsg'
video = pafy.new(url)
video.viewcount
```

Please make sure you `pip install youtube_dl`